# Yii2 Select2 Always Showing Placeholder Instead of Database Values

Tags: php, yii, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I have a problem with my Yii2 Select2 field because it's not retrieving inserted values from the database, showing the placeholder all the time.
I tried using a method to retrieve the inserted values from the database and put them in the `'value'` field attribute, but when saving the form they **resulted in duplicate entries**, meaning that the real records are still in the field but kinda hidden.
What can I do about it to show the inserted values in the Select2?

This is the form field

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    <?php $users = ArrayHelper::map(Profile::getActiveUsers(), 'id', 'name');
        echo $form->field($model, 'assignment', ['options' => [
            'class' => 'form-group form-group-default form-group-default-select2']])
                ->widget(Select2::className(), [
                    'data' => $users,
                    'options' => [
                        'placeholder' => 'Select users...',
                        'multiple' => true,
                    ],
                    'pluginOptions' => [
                        'allowClear' => true,
                        'multiple' => true,
                    ],
                    'theme' => Select2::THEME_DEFAULT,
        ])->label('Users');?>
</div>
```

I tried adding inside 'options' something like `'value' => methodToGetInsertedValues()` but as I said before, it gives error of **duplicate entries**

Comment: You're using 'multiple' => true in the plugonOptions. It can only be used in options:
                    ``'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Select users...','multiple' => true,],
                    'pluginOptions' => ['allowClear' => true,],``

Answer (score 0):

Managed to solve the issue by **setting the value** in my action controller.
I **retrieved the records**, **assigned them** to the field value, and **delete them all** before saving the model.

Something like

```
$model->modelField = ModelName::getRecords($model->id);
```

then before saving the model

```
ModelName::deleteAll(['id' => $model->id]);
```